# Integrating Mysql, Terminal, and a script

Tags: mysql, terminal

I'd like to import a mysql dump created on my production server and copy it to a local database on a regular basis.  So far I understand how to perform the actions in Terminal on my Mac and how to create a bash script that I can call through either Terminal or Applescript; I'll  use Applescript to run the script which will be called through iCal on a daily basis. When I perform the operations in sequential order in the Terminal, the Terminal "knows" that I've connected to MySQL, as the prompt changes to a MySQL prompt after I type the first line:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot;
DROP DATABASE `test_db`;
```

However, when I call the bash script with these commands, the second line is generating an error "test_db: command not found".  My guess is that in my script I'll need to somehow make it clear that the second line is specifically a MySQL operation.  Any help in achieving this would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help another noob like myself!  You can use:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -uroot -proot drop 'test_db' -f;
```

to drop a database.  mysqladmin ([check it out here)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html#option_mysqladmin_force)

can do a lot of the admin tasks from the command line.  My -f at the end forces the drop without being asked whether I want it to happen.